# Manual implementation of Matlab spectogram function

Tags: matlab, fft

I am trying to implement my own function that gives the same results as Matlab spectogram function.
So far I have accomplished function like this:

```
function out = manulaSpectogram(x, win, noverlap, nfft)
x = x(:);
n = length(x);
wlen = length(win);
nUnique = ceil((1+nfft)/2); % number of uniqure points
L = fix((n-noverlap)/(wlen-noverlap)); % number of signal frames
out = zeros(L, nUnique);
index = 1:wlen;
    for i = 0:L-1
        xw = win.*x(index);
        X = fft(xw, nfft);
        out(i+1, :) = X(1:nUnique);
        index = index + (wlen - noverlap);
    end
end
```

In my tests it works perfectly and gives the same results like spectogram function when parameter nfft is greater or equal to length of window.

```
% first test (nnft = window length):
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
window = 6;
overlap = 2;
nfft = 6;
s = spectrogram(A, hamming(window), overlap, nfft)'
s2 = manulaSpectogram(A, hamming(window), overlap, nfft)
% results:
s =
   9.7300 + 0.0000i  -5.2936 + 0.9205i   0.7279 - 0.3737i  -0.1186 + 0.0000i
s2 =
   9.7300 + 0.0000i  -5.2936 - 0.9205i   0.7279 + 0.3737i  -0.1186 + 0.0000i
   
% second test (nfft > window length):
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
window = 3;
overlap = 2;
nfft = 6;
s = spectrogram(A, hamming(window), overlap, nfft)'
s2 = manulaSpectogram(A, hamming(window), overlap, nfft)
% results:
s =
   2.3200 + 0.0000i   0.9600 + 1.9399i  -1.0400 + 1.5242i  -1.6800 + 0.0000i
   3.4800 + 0.0000i   1.5000 + 2.8752i  -1.5000 + 2.3209i  -2.5200 + 0.0000i
   4.6400 + 0.0000i   2.0400 + 3.8105i  -1.9600 + 3.1177i  -3.3600 + 0.0000i
   5.8000 + 0.0000i   2.5800 + 4.7458i  -2.4200 + 3.9144i  -4.2000 + 0.0000i
   
s2 =
   2.3200 + 0.0000i   0.9600 - 1.9399i  -1.0400 - 1.5242i  -1.6800 + 0.0000i
   3.4800 + 0.0000i   1.5000 - 2.8752i  -1.5000 - 2.3209i  -2.5200 + 0.0000i
   4.6400 + 0.0000i   2.0400 - 3.8105i  -1.9600 - 3.1177i  -3.3600 + 0.0000i
   5.8000 + 0.0000i   2.5800 - 4.7458i  -2.4200 - 3.9144i  -4.2000 + 0.0000i
```

In the case when length of window is less than nfft than the results are different.

```
% third test (nfft < window length):
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
window = 6;
overlap = 2;
nfft = 3;
s = spectrogram(A, hamming(window), overlap, nfft)'
s2 = manulaSpectogram(A, hamming(window), overlap, nfft)
% results:
s =
   9.7300 + 0.0000i   0.7279 - 0.3737i
 
s2 =
   3.6121 + 0.0000i  -1.6861 + 1.6807i
```

So how can I improve my function to recieve the same results even in the case when nnft is less than window length? How Matlab's spectogram calculates this case?

I am trying to implement my own function because a spectogram function is a part of a large algorithm which I need to implement from Matlab to C# language so I would like to know what spectogram "black box" does..

Comment: From the Matlab documentation for [`fft`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html): "Transform length, [...] If n is less than the length of the signal, then fft ignores the remaining signal values past the nth entry and returns the truncated result.[...]." Since the spectrogram is based on the fft, I'm assuming it's the same, just read "length of signal" as "length of window" instead.

Comment: So what should I modify in my function based on your comment?

Comment: Why not take a look at the code of the `spectrogram` function and its helper functions `pspectrogram` and `computeDFT`? The latter includes a code section with comment `Handle the case where NFFT is less than the segment length, i.e., "wrap"
the data as appropriate`, which is probably what you want. It calls the `datawrap` function

Comment: Where could I find the code of `spectogram` funcion?

Comment: @LuisMendo you are right. I didn't find the source code of `spectogram` function but as you suggested I called `datawrap` matlab inner function (which wraps input data modulo nfft) when window size is greater than `nfft` and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that when window size is greater than nfft scalar number, the data has to be transformed somehow. Finally I found an inner Matlab function that probably is called in the original `spectogram` Matlab function. It is named `datawrap` and wraps input data modulo nfft.

So in my function I had to transform data segment (in the same way how datawrap function does it) before calling fft.
Improved function:

```
function out = manulaSpectogram(x, win, noverlap, nfft)
x = x(:);
n = length(x);
wlen = length(win);
nUnique = ceil((1+nfft)/2); % number of uniqure points
L = fix((n-noverlap)/(wlen-noverlap)); % number of signal frames
out = zeros(L, nUnique);
index = 1:wlen;
    for i = 0:L-1
        xw = win.*x(index);
        % added transformation
        if length(xw) > nfft
            xw = sum(buffer(xw, nfft), 2);
        end
        % end of added transformation
        X = fft(xw, nfft);
        out(i+1, :) = X(1:nUnique);
        index = index + (wlen - noverlap);
    end
end
```

I believe it works properly because it gives the same results as Matlab `spectogram` function.

Answer (score 0):

With the window you are calculating the ends of the block to zero. This needs as mandatory, that the vector lengths of the window and the FFT-Block are the same. Matlab allows with the default parameters unequal values: nsc is not equal to nff (see Matlab docu spectrogram with default). An error message would be necessary if different block length for the window and nff occur. Matlab spectrogram with default parameter for my opinion is wrong. Compare with LabView, Dasylab, Hewlett-Packard and http://www.schmid-werren.ch/hanspeter/publications/2012fftnoise.pdf

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).